# Translating Volume {id} to physical drive letter or even Serial Number?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

One of my drives keeps having problems in Windows 7 boot sequence.
I get:

> The file system structure on the disk is corrupt and unusable. Please run the chkdsk utility on the volume \\?\Volume{091ae807-d359-443e-8bb1-1bfef9a0db26}

I found a thread referring to `mountvol` and a utility `dd` to identify it.

But the output doesn't match the troubled volume.

Is there something I'm just not getting? Any ideas how to identify the naughty drive?

```
C:\Users\ProductionSDD>mountvol

Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point.

MOUNTVOL [drive:]path VolumeName MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /D MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /L MOUNTVOL [drive:]path /P MOUNTVOL /R MOUNTVOL /N MOUNTVOL /E

    path        Specifies the existing NTFS directory where the mount
                point will reside.
    VolumeName  Specifies the volume name that is the target of the mount
                point.
    /D          Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory.
    /L          Lists the mounted volume name for the specified directory.
    /P          Removes the volume mount point from the specified directory,
                dismounts the volume, and makes the volume not mountable.
                You can make the volume mountable again by creating a volume
                mount point.
    /R          Removes volume mount point directories and registry settings
                for volumes that are no longer in the system.
    /N          Disables automatic mounting of new volumes.
    /E          Re-enables automatic mounting of new volumes.

Possible values for VolumeName along with current mount points are:

    \\?\Volume{3631d6cc-bd74-11e5-81ef-806e6f6e6963}\
        E:\

    \\?\Volume{bb40a0df-b9a1-11e5-bfd8-806e6f6e6963}\
        *** NO MOUNT POINTS ***

    \\?\Volume{3631d6ce-bd74-11e5-81ef-806e6f6e6963}\
        F:\

    \\?\Volume{1a62644b-679f-4e7a-9727-7d28e7256056}\
        I:\

    \\?\Volume{3631d6cf-bd74-11e5-81ef-806e6f6e6963}\
        G:\

    \\?\Volume{3631d6cd-bd74-11e5-81ef-806e6f6e6963}\
        H:\

    \\?\Volume{bb40a0e0-b9a1-11e5-bfd8-806e6f6e6963}\
        C:\
```

Comment: Have you considered it is a USB drive you don’t have plugged in right now?

Comment: Note that drive letters _aren't_ any more or less "physical" than volume paths (they're aliases), and you don't need a drive letter for chkdsk and other operations. Run `chkdsk \\?\Volume{091ae807-d359-443e-8bb1-1bfef9a0db26}` (without a trailing backslash) and it'll be checked.

Comment: Nope no USB drives. 
I don't want to check the drive, it's been checked multiple times.  
I just want to back it up and then Put a few nails through it ! Hahah!